# Using coldfusion session id for SSO authentication

Tags: coldfusion, single-sign-on, coldfusion-9, sessionid

I am integrating a 3rd party application. It will be embedded into my site via an iframe. When instantiating the iframe, a username and unique id(sessionid) is sent to the third party app in this format:

> `http://www.thirdpartyapp.com?username=9999999&uuid=appname_11111_d3d379ab97c23930-154C9639-1CC4-6169-286F5EB34A37B3C3`

Once the user on the site tries to use any of the functions inside the Iframe, the 3rd party app sends back the `sessionid` to the server, to validate if the session is logged in.

If a user is logged in, the application sets a session variable such as `Session.Auth.Authenticated` to true.

I am able to achieve this by using `CFID` and `CFTOKEN` like so:

> `http://www.mysite.com/checkauth/index.cfm?CFID=2223344&CFTOKEN=40487e5933d11e75-F94396AF-1CC4-6169-28200888416FFC`

The third party app sends requests in the format:

> `http://www.mysite.com/checkauth/index.cfm?uuid=appname_11111_d3d379ab97c23930-154C9639-1CC4-6169-286F5EB34A37B3C3`

Basically the same format as my site makes the request. Is there any way to check authenticated sessions using the `session.sessionid`?

Comment: So your iframe's source is `http://www.thirdpartyapp.com?username=9999999&uuid=appname_11111_d3d379ab97c23930-154C9639-1CC4-6169-286F5EB34A37B3C3`?  It seems like this sort of thing is usually done with cfhttp conversations.

Comment: @travis, yes the iframes source will be that. I am just concerned on how to validate user logged in session using that sessionid.

Answer (score 1):

> "Is there any way to check authenticated sessions using the
>   Session.sessionid?"

Seems like it is possible. The ColdFusion `sessionid` is consists of three things:

```
       appName_CFIDE_CFTOKEN
```

In your case the format of the url parameter of the request send by third party application is same as `session.sessionId`:

```
       appname_11111_d3d379ab97c23930-154C9639-1CC4-6169-286F5EB34A37B3C3
```

Now if you enable "Use UUID for cftoken" in CF Admin under "settings" section you will get session id like the following:

```
       PLANTOMATIC_11201_1f8a073a0ba85bf5-2F7356F3-BE59-A0B4-F3E493BD794062C6
```

So what you need to do is apply the setting "Use UUID for cftoken" in CF Admin. Then you can send request to the third party like following:

```
       http://www.thirdpartyapp.com?username=9999999&uuid=#session.sessionid#
```

Which will respond back with parameter "uuid". After that you can check for equality and take the necessary steps.